# I'm wondering how I can get push messages from remote servers in the background on Android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, push-notification

I'm really curious how Android (using the java language) usually implements the processing that allows users to send real-time push alarms even when they're not using the app.

- Various messenger apps (alarm when messages are received)
- Weather app
- Various bank apps (alarm when deposited or withdrawn)
- Event messages from other apps

There are two ways I've looked into it.

The first method is socket.
I am good at handling web sockets on node.js server and web client.

But on Android, I didn't know how to use a socket, so I looked it up.

Android used the following code.
Socket socket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 9989);
Log.i("test", "good!");

And the node.js server wrote the following code.
ws.on("connect", connectHandler);

but
The "good" log was successfully printed on Android
The node.js server has confirmed that the connectHandler method is not running.
What's the problem?

Is the socket a common implementation method?
If it's right, if it's an application with 10 million users
Are 10 million clients simultaneously accessing the server by socket?

The second method I've learned is Firebase Cloud Messaging
If I run an Instagram-sized app, will it be a paid service?

The app I want to create is Instagram, which is used by about a million people.

- Alarm when DM is received
- If you leave a comment or like on my post, an alarm will pop up
- Other types of alarms

The whole point of the question is
More than a million users are always connected to the server in the background
You can receive messages at any time.

Thank you very much for reading the long article, and I look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, push notifications are implemented using **FCM**

I've never developed it with a socket, but my opinion is that the app has to keep the socket connected continuously, so there's probably a problem with the app's battery usage.

FCM's cost seems free, and you can check it out on that link.
https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: In the case of messenger apps, real-time processing is important, so it would be efficient to process them with socket in foreground.

Comment: I always thought that Firebase costs when you start using it more intensively ? Is that not true anymore ?

Comment: When it comes to cloudmessage, it seems to be unlimited free and costs are incurred when using authentication, Cloud Firestore, etc.